# Angularjs ng-class toggles class when in a child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my example I expect my child item to be active when it is displayed (that works fine). Then when I click on that item I still expect that Item to be active (not working). Instead the active class is toggled on and off every time its clicked.

The ideas is that I could have multiple items displayed and anyone of them could be active, so I do have a method that clears all items before setting the active item.

I can make this work correctly when using $timeout after clearing the active item.

**Example:** [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/QXGrEIUYqNzr7qaACCQq?p=preview)

So my question is, Why do I have to use $timeout here when a digest is already taking place?   or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a proof of concept, that might solve your problem

http://jsfiddle.net/UDc2E/

Basically i have a child directive, that registers deactivation callbacks with a parent ctrl, that get called, when an item is "activated"

var module = angular.module("app",[]);

```
module.controller("Ctrl",["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.items=[
        {active:true,text:"1"},
        {active:false,text:"2"}
    ];
}]);
module.directive("activationGroup",[function(){
    return {
        restrict:"A",
        controller: function($scope) {
            var onDeactivationCallBacks = [];

            this.register = function(onDeactivation){
                onDeactivationCallBacks.push(onDeactivation);
            }
            this.trigger = function() {
                angular.forEach(onDeactivationCallBacks,function(cb){

                    cb();
                })
            }
        }
    }
}]);
module.directive("activationItem",["$parse",function($parse){
    return {
        restrict:"A",
        require:"^activationGroup",
        link: function($scope,$element,$attrs,activationGroupCtrl){
            var onActivationCB = function(){
                var f = $parse($attrs.onActivation);
                return function(){
                    f($scope);
                }
            }();
            var onDeactivationCB = function(){
                var f = $parse($attrs.onDeactivation);
                return function(){
                    f($scope);
                }
            }();
            activationGroupCtrl.register(onDeactivationCB);
            $element.on("click", function(){
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    activationGroupCtrl.trigger();
                    onActivationCB();
                });            
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

regards

Comment: Thanks! I'm following your code and find it interesting, but I feel like I'm still missing something. Is there an advantage to doing it this way versus a simpler approach like @GRaAL suggests.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to how two-way binding is implemented in angular. What is actually hapenned when you click on item and 'activate' function called:

1. You call to the function 'clearActive' which modifies parent scope and sets 'active' property of your item to false
2. Then you change the 'active' property of the current scope to true.
3. After this digest is finished the angular.js runs one more to check that there is no more changes. This new digest found that 'item.active' property is changed to false and updates 'active' property of scope of your child directive to false, overwriting your previous change

I'd like to suggest passing item itself to the child directive instead of just 'active' property - here is [fork of your plunker which works that way](http://plnkr.co/edit/YLvv7uTcrs3AGkEv6Czy?p=preview).